# proof for the uniqueness of exterior derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

To prove the uniqueness of the exterior derivative which as $\mathbb{R}$ -linear map $d:\Omega(M) \to \Omega(M)$,which satisfy the following 3 conditions:

1. d is antiderivation with degree 1
2. $d\circ d = 0$
3. if f is a smooth function and X is smooth vector field on M then $df(X) = Xf$

To prove the uniqueness,we need to use the bump function to extend to local representation $d\omega = \sum a_Idx^I$(on a chart $(U,(x^i))$) to global smooth function $a_I$ and global $dx^I$

The question is why extension here is necessary?(There are many proof in smooth manifold use bump function to extend the local field,and function to global one.For calculation it typically seems no harm?The reason is just to fit the domain of the function well so we extend it correct?)

For example here since by condition (3) exterior derivative is unique for any smooth function  on $M$ (i.e. $\Omega^0(M)$),that is $df = Df$ for any other $D$,but it need not to be the local $f$ since domain of D only eat global smooth function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in full detail in the proof of **Theorem 14.24** in J. Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*. I will give a brief sketch why this is needed.

The most important thing is to observe that $d$ is a *local operator* – for every differential form $\omega$ and point $p$ of $M$, the value $d\omega|_p$ is fully determined by $\omega|_{U}$, where $U$ is any open neighborhood of $p$. I will formulate this precisely as:

**Lemma**: Let $p\in M$ and $\omega_1, \omega_2\in \Omega^*(M)$. If for some open neighborhood $U$ of $p$, we have $$\omega_1|_U=\omega_2|_U,$$
then $$d\omega_1|_{p}=d\omega_2|_{p}.$$

*(You may have already seen a similar statement: a tangent vector $v_p$ is often introduced as a differential operator. There is a small lemma showing that $v_p(f_1)=v_p(f_2)$ if $f_1$ and $f_2$ are smooth functions that agree on some open neighborhood of $p$. Not only is the statement almost the same – so is the proof.)*

**Proof:** Using the linearity (consider the difference $\omega_1-\omega_2$), it suffices to prove: if $\omega|_U=0$, then $d\omega|_p = 0$. To prove this, consider a bump function $b$ that vanishes outside some smaller neighborhood than $U$. In other words, $b(p)=1$, $db|_p=0$ and $b\omega = 0$ on $M$. Hence,
$$0 = d(b\omega) = db\wedge \omega + b\,d\omega.$$
By evaluating this at $p$ we get the claim.

**Why is the extension necessary?** Let's take a point $p$ and any coordinate patch $(U, x^i)$. Restrict a form $\omega \in \Omega^*(M)$ to $\omega|_U \in \Omega^*(U)$, so that $\omega|_{U} = \omega_I\, dx^I$. *Let's ignore for a moment the fact that this is not a form defined on the whole $M$ and see what its exterior derivative should be.*

One can prove that the three properties of $d$ fully determine it:
$$d(\omega_I\,dx^I) = d\omega_I\wedge dx^I.$$
I will not do the full proof here – it's simple induction. To sketch an idea, let's do it for one-forms. By linearity it suffices to consider expressions of the form $f\,dx^i$. Then using the three properties, we have $d(dx^i)=0$ and
$$d(f\, dx^i) = f\, d(dx^i) + df \wedge dx^i = df\wedge dx^i.$$

Hence, we know how $d$ *should* act on $\omega|_{U}$ in every coordinate patch. It is easy to check that for another  coordinate patch, $(V, y^j)$ such that $V\cap U$ is non-empty, we arrive with the same result.

Let's go back to the problem with extension: *we cannot apply $d$ to $\omega|_U$!* Exterior derivative $d$ accepts forms defined *on the whole of $M$*.

We need a simple trick here. Instead of working with function $\omega_I$ (defined only on $U$), extend it to a function $\tilde \omega_I$ defined on the whole of $M$ by a bump function. Analogously extend coordinate functions $x^i$ on $U$ to (non-coordinate) functions $\tilde x^i$ on $M$. We have now a differential form $\tilde \omega = \tilde \omega_I \, d\tilde x^I$, defined on the whole of $M$! Obviously, on some neighborhood $V$ of $p$, we have $\tilde\omega|_V = \omega|_V$. Hence, we can use the lemma and get
$$d\omega|_p = d\tilde \omega|_p,$$
what finishes the proof.

---

**Can't we "make it local" from the beginning?** A tangent vector $v_p$ is often defined as a differential operator that turns functions defined on $M$ into real numbers. But the (slightly reworded) lemma above shows that it in facts depends *only on the local behaviour around $p$*. In other words, $v_p$ can be defined as a collection of maps
$$v_p^U : C^\infty(U)\to \mathbb R,$$
where $U$ ranges over all open neighborhoods of $p$ (as usual, $v_p^U$ are assumed to be linear and obey the Leibniz's rule) such that for any two neighborhoods $V\subseteq U$ and a function $f\in C^\infty(U)$, an equality
$$v_p^U(f) = v_p^V(f|_V)$$
holds.

Why do these definitions agree? Surely having a collection $\{v_p^U\}$, we can recover $v_p$ simply as $v_p^M$. On the other hand, having $v_p$ we can construct the collection $\{v_p^U\}$ by virtue of (a reworded version of) the lemma above – take a bump function $b$, extend $f\in C^\infty(U)$ to a function $\tilde f\in C^\infty(M)$ and put
$$v_p^U(f) = v_p(\tilde f).$$

*Remark: The above may be reworded using the language of sheaves – we are basically passing between derivations on $C^\infty(M)$ and derivations on a stalk $C^\infty_p$. This is done using bump functions and this is not possible e.g. on real-analytic or complex manifolds.*

A similar thing holds for differential forms: B. Conrad in his [handouts](https://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/diffgeomPage/handouts/dmap.pdf) constructs exterior derivative using the "local" approach – he defines a collection of maps $d^U\colon \Omega^*(U)\to \Omega^{*+1}(U)$ satisfying properties you listed and the property of "being local": if $V\subseteq U$ and $\omega$ is a section of $U$, then $(d^U\omega)|_V = d^V(\omega|_V)$.
Then he proves that this family of maps is uniquely determined.

It is easy to see that both definitions are equivalent: from a collection $\{d^U\}$ we can recover globally-defined $d$ as $d^M$. Conversely, by the discussion above, we can pass from $d$ to the collection $\{d^U\}$ by extending the arguments by bump functions.